# Opencv cannot be imported into container

Tags: python, docker, opencv, nvidia-jetson

I need to install Opencv inside container and this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev
RUN pip install numpy==1.14.6 --no-binary numpy --force-reinstall

RUN pip install python-opencv

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
EXPOSE 5020
```

And this is the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

I tried almost everything:
apt-get install,
pip3 install,
pip install.

Please help

Comment: Are you using PowerShell to run your Docker Image?

Comment: No, Its dockerfile included in the Edge Module azure, running in vscode.

Comment: I guess it is easier to debug if run it on a local Docke Image

Comment: If I include one more image into this docker container for opencv, Will it be included and import cv2 error will go away rgt?

Comment: It has to be deployed from a remote machine, hence local deploy wont be option because I need opencv inside this container

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. I have not experienced the same problem my self, but please consider following this site https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124022/docker-container . We want to make a space where people can share their Docker issues. There is almost no answers to questions related to Docker here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure will do it. But I would love to get a proper solution to this q.

Comment: Yes, I would really like you to get an answer to your question too and I think the best solution is to actually create a forum for docker users

Comment: shouldn't it be `pip install opencv-python` instead of `python-opencv`?

Comment: Hi @Miki Yes u r correct. But I tried that too, But wasnt successful.